# Android tags and logcat

Tags: feature-request, tags, warning

Since we'll always find questions asking about exceptions being generated without showing the logcat contents, is it possible to always display a warning whenever the user uses the words "android" and "exception" in the question?

I say "uses the words" because I suspect that when people use tags appropriately, they are more likely to ask the question with the proper elements. But any alternative would be ok.

Of course, I'm just asking if it's possible (and, in case so, if it's desirable). This could possibly be extended to other tags as well.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the worthwhile idea, but I see a `status-declined` in your future.

Comment: No problem. I just wanted to warn the people responsible for features implementation that it is a frequent problem and a huge time waster for everyone. Of course, that's not up to me to decide, and that's ok. :-)

Comment: +1 the android tag is one of the **most popular tags** and the absence of the logcat is of the most frequent problems there.